# Replacing a disk with ZFS

Tags: macos, raid, zfs

I've been using ZFS for a RAID on my mac for the past few months and a few days ago one of the disks died. The computer didn't recognize it anymore, it shut off seconds after being turned on and made weird noises.
So I got a new drive and used

```
sudo zpool replace RAIDNAMEHERE olddisk newdisk
```

Oddly the two disk identifiers were the same according to diskutil list (disk3s2)

Now I get this:

```
Destiny-Ascension:~ AreusAstarte$ zpool status
pool: DeltaRaidPi
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
scrub: resilver in progress, 0,01% done, 312h37m to go
config:

NAME               STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
DeltaRaidPi        DEGRADED     0     0     0
  raidz1           DEGRADED     0     0     0
    disk5s2        ONLINE       0     0     0
    disk4s2        ONLINE       0     0     0
    replacing      DEGRADED     0     0     0
      disk3s2/old  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
      disk3s2      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Now I could use some help. From the documentation about ZFS it wasn't really clear to me what I need to do now. Is there actually already data on disk3s2? Will that be taken care of automatically and when will I be able to remove the old disk from that overview so that the raid will register as ONLINE again?

Sorry if this is a noob question but I'm not very experienced with these kinda things :P Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message states you have to wait for about a couple of weeks for the resilver to complete. This is I hope pessimistic so might be somewhat shortened.

In the meantime, you can monitor the I/Os on your machine with `zpool iostat` or perhaps `iostat` if available to figure out what rates your devices are showing.

Comment: Ah yea...I just saw that. It went down to 24 hours. The drives are smoking hot right now but in 4 hours it'll all be done :P The raid saves data on the other drives as counter-bits, doesn't it? So resilvering means restoring that and copying it onto the third drive?

Comment: Precisely. That's how it works.

Comment: Since resilvering is done in order of "importance", rather than sequentially, it involves a huge amount of seeking particularly at the beginning. When adding a mirror device, for example, with internal spinning-platter HDDs it's not unreasonable to see resilver speeds on the order of a few hundred *kilobytes* per second. It picks up speed after a while, but the projected time remaining doesn't take that into account until it actually happens.